# Deserialization and serialization of navigation maps

Tags: python, serialization, nao-robot, pepper

I made an exploration with my Pepper and then I got the metrical representation of the map with [ALNavigationProxy::getMetricalMap()](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/exploration-api.html#ALNavigationProxy::getMetricalMap). Now I want to make some changes to this metrical representation of the map - for example to change the coordinates of the beginning point (0, 0, 0). How can I then serialize this changed metrical data back to `.expo` file so Pepper can load it and navigate in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifing the .explo file is not supported.
However for you application display you can save your modified version of your getMetricalMap data (serializing your own way) and display it instead of the real getMetricalMap of the robot. This way you can also show instead an architectural plan  or any drawing of your choice. If you do, be sure that scale, origin, and orientation match.

Comment: Your proposal is good, but it won't work for me. I need to create my own map and give it to the robot. I guess that would be one very good feature for next versions of naoqi.

Comment: Are you completely sure .explo file modification is not supported?

Comment: Yes, not supported for now.
There is nothing in the documentation (http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/exploration-api.html?highlight=explore) that mentions it.